# Read PDF with NodeJS and render the context in the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I want to display a PDF on a canvas, without let the client know the PDF url. 
I want to use pdfjs in a way that my server (nodejs) will take the PDF url and parse the PDF, then sent it to the client and the client will display the context on the canvas. 
Is there a way to do that? Thanks you!

Comment: I think you have a valid question here but it's difficult to answer without more context https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **pdfreader** package from NPM.

Example code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("sample.pdf", (err, pdfBuffer) => {
  // pdfBuffer contains the file content
  new PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    else if (!item) callback();
    else if (item.text) console.log(item.text);
  });
});
```

Read more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader

Comment: And how I display the content on the web canvas?

Comment: @ZivSdeor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704175/writing-text-on-image-with-npm-node-canvas-in-custom-language